# Android getting permission for Live TV Channels

Tags: android

I just created Live TV app for Android Mobile and uploaded in googleplay. But they rejected for Violations of terms and conditions.

How can I get permission to show those channels in my app.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.techndroid.cricketlivestreaming">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LiveStreaming"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".Ptv"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >

        </activity>
       
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any Help?

Comment: Share your Manifest file

Comment: @Akshay I Added My Manifest

Comment: also have you added a privacy policy?

Comment: No I just Submitted App. No privacy policy submitted

Comment: You will need to add it

Comment: Ok But I didn't have any permission to use channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not added a privacy policy.Try adding privacy policy by following steps:
1.Log into your Google Play Developer Console
2.Select All Applications.
3.Select (your) application.
4.Click Store Listing.
5.Go to the Privacy Policy field.
6.Enter the URL where you host the policy. ...
7.Click Save.

It should work